# implementation other module method

Tags: gradle, dependencies, implementation

I'm developing multi-module project, and my problem is how to reference method in other module.

my project structure is

```
module1
module2
common
db
```

gradle file is

```
project(':module1') {
dependencies {
    implementation project(':db')
    implementation project(':common')
}

project(':module2') {
dependencies {
    //things what i want to do is here
    implementation proeject(':module1:some method only')

    implementation project(':db')
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

Can I make it?
The reason why I try to this is b/c I only need a few method in module1.

Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: Where are those methods defined, in `module1`'s `build.gradle` or Java code under the `src` folder?

Comment: @chehsunliu it's java code. under the src folder.